# Search on the content in asp.net web site

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, content-management-system

I have developed a website in asp.net 4.0 I have given Content Management where user will able to enter Title, short description and the html content using CK Editor. This content is then saved in a specific folder in a root directory. I want user to search the web site based on this content. How can I do that.

Comment: Please at least attempt to do it yourself before posting here. If you get stuck the ask a question about any specific problem.

Comment: First I have tried with keywords i.e along with the content I enable user to mention some keywords from content upon which search  will do from SQL. But I think this is not a correct way. Secondly I was thinking of search for the keyword within a saved file using System.IO.Directory.GetFiles... method but I think this will not good idea in Web architecture.

Comment: Since you haven't mentioned a database, perhaps try using [Lucene.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms). You can create a search index for your content with it.